# Programmatically switch User

Tags: android, api

I was wondering if there is an API call to switch users in Android. The behaviour I want is to switch programmatically users on one device (and respectably their apps as well), when something happens. Is this even possible?

I did not find anything [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html) or [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

Comment: Check out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487602/android-how-to-programmatically-switch-users-by-user-name